# Counting / characterizing the isolated points of a particular algebraic variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, differential-topology, lower-bounds

I'm not a professional geometer / topologist, so please thanks for your patience :)

## Setup

The following questions are the first in a series of steps I'm undertaking in an attempt to break down a [bigger question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/314717) (MO link) into standalone chewable pieces.

So, let $F$ be a field (e.g $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb C$, $\mathbb F_2$, etc.), $n$, $p$, $q$, and $r$ be positive integers and let $F^{n \times p}$ and $Y \in F^{n \times r}$ be fixed matrices. Consider the system of equations in unknown matrices $U \in F^{p \times q}$ and $V \in F^{q \times r}$
$$
\begin{split}
X^T(XUV - Y)V^T &= 0 \in F^{p \times q},\\
U^TX^T(XUV - Y) &= 0 \in F^{q \times r}.
\end{split}
$$

Note that this is a system of polynomial equations in the entries of the matrices $U$ and $V$. Thus the set of solutions to the above system of equations is an algebraic variety $\Omega$ over the field $F$. I'm interested in the geometry and topology of $\Omega$ (number and nature of isolated points, connected components, etc.).

## Possible questions

- What is a good upper bound on the number of isolated points of $\Omega$ ?
- What is a good upper bound on the average number of isolated points of $\Omega$ when the rows of $X$ and $Y$ are random i.i.d ?

## Observations

- My wild guess is that some kind of [Bézout theorem][2] should be applicable here, but I don't have any experience with that theory.
- The two matricial equations above have a common factor $X^T(XUV-Y)$.
- Symmetries: It's easy to see that if $(U,V) \in \Omega$ and $A$ is an invertible $p$-by-$p$ matrix, then $(UA^{-1},AV) \in \Omega$.
  Thus the mapping $(A, (U, V)) \mapsto (UA^{-1},AV)$ defines a group-action on $\Omega$, of $\operatorname{GL}_p$, the *linear* algebraic group of invertible $p$-by-$p$ matrices. Furthermore this group-action is *regular*. See comment section of [this related question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/314717) (MO link).

Maybe these observations can be exploited somehow in the answer ?

## Updates

- A user has remarked that the group-action above implies that the only possible isolated point of $\Omega$ is the origin $(U=0,V=0)$. Consequently it has also been suggested that a better question is counting the number of isolated *orbits*. So

## Further questions

*(A)* What's the structure / size of the quotient "$\Omega/\operatorname{GL}_p$" ?

*(B)* More "precisely",

- How many isolated orbits does $\Omega$ have ?

  - Can we describe / characterize them ?
  - What are their dimensions ?
  - etc.
- Same questions as above, but for *connected* components.
- Same questions as above, but for *irreducible* components
- etc.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, there seems to be a size mismatch. $X^T X W_0 W_1$ is $p_0 \times p_2$, while $X^T Y$ is $p_0 \times p_1$. Is $Y$ supposed to be $n \times p_2$?

Comment: Thanks for catching. Yes it was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: I don't see why the group action preserves the solution set. E.g. consider the term $X^T Y W_1$ in the first equation... But if you did have such a group action, the only possible isolated point is the origin, since that's the only fixed point of this action.

Comment: Oh... If you put $W_1^T$ in the first equation your symmetries work, and then my previous comment applies.

Comment: Thanks. Tha was a typo. It should indeed be $W_1^T$.  Fixed. Also you mean "... doesnt apply" right ? :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant the *second* part of my comment applies: with such a symmetry group, the only possible isolated point is the origin. A more interesting question might thus be to ask about isolated *orbits*, but I suppose that depends on your motivation.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow OK, I misread you. Thanks for clarifying. Q: I think I'm still missing something, but why is every isolated point of $\Omega$ also a fixed point for that group action ? Is this somehow related to the fact that my group action is continuous ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. Your group is connected, and every orbit is the image of the group under a polynomial map (namely, the orbit of a point p is the image of the map $g \mapsto g.p$), so every orbit is connected.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow So a better question to ask is then "How many connected components does $\Omega$ have ?". Correct ? I've updated the question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Connected components is a potentially interesting question, sure. FYI, it need not be the same as # of isolated orbits, e.g. consider the action of the circle by rotations on a cylinder: 1 connected component, no isolated orbits. Given that your equations are polynomials, another standard question to ask is # of *irreducible* components. You can then ask about which ones intersect, the structure of their intersections, their singular loci, dimensions of all of these objects, etc.

Comment: OK, gotcha. Thanks for the remarks. Question updated / improved. So, is there any "standard" ways to answer any of these questions then ? Thanks in advance

Comment: I would replace $W_0, W_1, p_0, p_1, p_2$ by $M, N, p, q, r$, and then factor out the $X^T$'s in the key equations.  That would make this easier to read, and less vulnerable to typos.

Comment: Indeed. Fix applied.

Comment: The simplest possible case is $n+p+q+r=4$, which are uninteresting scalar equations, so the next step in simplification might be analyzing some particular cases with $n+p+q+r$ equal to 5 or 6.

Comment: Hum, ya indeed the case $n=p=q=r=1$ is not very interesting: $\Omega$ reduces to a union of a hyperbolic surface (with 2 disjoint pieces for $Y \ne 0$) and the coordinate axes.